# How to install App on Apple Watch

Tags: ios, iphone, apple-watch

I have created the watch App and able to run on the simulator. But now i wanted to run the app on my iPhone. What is the process to achieve this?

So far have updated provisioning profile in my iOS Code.

Comment: Below… where, exactly?

Comment: Sorry Noah, have updated

Comment: Also i have created the App, Like we create .app for iOS and upload to switcboard. So is this the similar way, I need to create??

Comment: You use the Apple Watch app on your iPhone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What have you already tried?

At any rate, here's a blog post that may help you: http://blog.jaredsinclair.com/post/117350678170/jareds-code-signing-tips-apple-watch-edition

Answer (score 2):

Since i have not an `Apple Watch` yet, But I have found that :

Pair Your iPhone & Apple Watch, setup your provisioning profiles for `Watch-app` & `extention` NOW....

`Apps` that include `aplle-Watch-extention` should automatically start installation on `Watch` when you start `iPhone App`(Parent App) installation.

[Here is the Video Link that illustrate briefly](http://www.cnet.com/how-to/apple-watch-apps-how-to-install-how-to-delete-how-they-work/)

Hope it'll help you... :)

Answer (score 1):

I went to the lab for watch. You just need two more provisioning profiles in order to test your applications on the watch. You don't really have to do anything on the watch. Once you install the hosted app, the watch app will be installed if you set up the provisioning profiles correctly.

You need one provisioning profile for the watch extension and another one for the watch app. Totally, you will have three app identifiers and three provisioning profiles in order to fully testing the hosted app and the watch app.